# how to decode this lua script code? I didn't understand what is in the function encode on line number seven

Tags: lua

How to understand what is written in encodes parameter?

```
print('Credits And Logs')
function encodes(key,code)
   return (code:gsub('..', function (h) return string.char((tonumber(h,16)+256-13 - key + 999999*256)%256) end))
end
local v_value=print({'Enter password'},{[1]=0},{[1]='number'})
print(encodes(v_value[1],'**BUNCHOFCODES**')
local enc = load(data)
print(enc)
```

Comment: The encoded text is a sequence of two-digit hexadecimal values `(ASCII+13+key) modulo 256`, where ASCII is the code of corresponding symbol in the original text

Comment: what value will be stored in v_value[1] which will be the key in encodes function?to undersand the data written we needs the key as well, isn't it? the main issue is to know the key value.

Comment: Yes, the key value is required for both encoding and decoding.  But the encryption is very weak, the key could be determined (by symbol frequency analysis).

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52187628/6834680)

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my answer. @EgorSkriptunoff